# Can I use the OR operator in <xsl:value-of select>?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, boolean-expression

I have been using the following piece of code to replace the regular expression `'\s*AND\s*NOT\s*scope:\("TEXT"\)'` with a specific string only if the match does not occurr (`non-matching-substring`):

```
<xsl:template name="strip-scopes">
                <xsl:param name="q" />
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='\s*AND\s*NOT\s*scope:\("TEXT"\)'>
                        <xsl:matching-substring></xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                   <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'AND \(scope:.*?\)',''), 'AND facet_.*?:\(.*?\)', '')"/>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

It works fine, but I now need to include another condition in the `<xsl:non-matching-string`>. Is it possible to include an OR condition inside the  element, so that both `'AND facet_.*?:\(.*?\)'` and `'AND NOT facet_.*?:\(.*?\)'` replacements can be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace(., 'foo|bar', 'whatever')` to have both `foo` and/or `bar` substrings replaced with `whatever`. The second argument of `replace` is a regular expression and therefore `|` allows alternatives.

Comment: thank you so much! I have been trying all sort of things and  it was so straightforward!